# Resounding positive vs resoundingly positive

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

When describing a situation where only positive feedback was received, which one is correct:

1. We received resoundingly positive feedback
2. We received resounding positive feedback

To my ears Nr 1. sounds more natural, but as "feedback" is being described the adjective form of Nr 2. makes more sense.

Comment: Was the feedback resounding and positive or was it resoundingly positive?

Comment: @KillingTime Can you elaborate on what the difference is? Am I providing different meaning with the two versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1. the adverb ***resoundingly*** intensifies the adjective ***positive***. It is as if saying:

> We received *VERY positive* feedback.

If you have a look at Cambridge's entry on *[intensifiers](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/intensifiers-very-at-all)*, this may become more clear to you.

In 2. the adjective ***resounding*** is in symmetry with the adjective ***positive***, both describing the noun ***feedback***. As if saying:

> We received feedback which was [resounding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resounding) (loud, emphatic) and positive.

So yes, you are expressing two different meanings with your two examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes any difference to the *meaning* which syntactic structure you use. Regardless of which "part of speech" you assign to ***resounding, resoundingly***, semantically they're both just "intensifiers". And [here's a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20resoundingly%20negative%20answer%2Ca%20resounding%20negative%20answer&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) for essentially the same construction...

[image]

...showing that both versions are about equally likely. It's quite true that *syntactically* we can distinguish between...

> 1: Adverbial ***resoundingly*** modifies ***negative*** - the *combination* modifies ***answer***
> and
> 2: Adjectival ***resounding*** modifies the compound noun ***negative answer***.

...but I can't believe any significant number of competent native speakers would distinguish two different meanings there and choose their words accordingly. It really is just a stylistic choice.